# How does the newton's third law generate enough lift to make the airplanes fly?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, aircraft, lift

How does the newton's 3rd law generate enough reaction so as to make the airplanes fly to great heights? The airplanes push air downwards but really is that enough to make the airplanes fly to great heights? What else contributes to lift? And how is angle of attack also so significant in contributing to the same? please provide a detailed answer and further links for research.....

Comment: It would be helpful if you could expand on why you don't think this is reasonable. This is one of those questions where to the asker it seems clear that a plane can't generate enough lift this way, while to the answerers it seems clear that it can. Closing that gap means understanding where the misunderstanding lies, detail appreciated

Comment: Newton's 3rd law doesn't generate anything. The lift is generated by the pressure difference across the wing, which in turn is generated by the velocity gradient across the wing (that follows from the Navier-Stoke's). You start deriving the lift force equation by considering a cylinder of diameter $D$ in a viscous flow. Since the flow is viscous, there is velocity gradient across the diameter from which you can deduce pressure difference across the diameter which acts on the cylinder in the direction perpendicular to the flow. Then use conformal geometry to convert the cylinder to the wing.

Comment: In order to understand what's going on, you have to take, AT LEAST, an introductory fluid mechanics course and an intermediate fluid mechanics course. The text book for the introductory course is Frank White's "Fluid mechanics" (any edition will do), the text book for the intermediate course is Robert Nunn's "Intermediate fluid mechanics" (any edition will work).

Answer (score 1):

> What else contributes to lift?

Nothing else. An airplane beats the air down with its wings, and to a lesser degree, with its fuselage; and the "equal and opposite" force to what accelerates the air downward is what lifts the airplane up. Air has more mass than many of us appreciate. The home office (repurposed bedroom) in which I am sitting right now contains maybe 75 kilograms of air.

> how is angle of attack...significant...?

That's pretty simple. When a wing passes through the air at a higher angle of attack, the volume of air that it must push out of the way is greater.

[image]

Of course, there's a problem if the angle is too high: The wing "stalls." But, if you want to know how that happens, it probably ought to be a whole new question.

> please provide...links for research

Sorry. I don't mind giving you a clue, but I don't have time to do your research for you.

Comment: Thanks , really for the answer. But how does the airfoil really "push" air downwards? And how come higher angle of attack , push more air downwards?

Comment: @Nuclearfusion, Top of the wing pulls air down because of the _Coandă effect._ You can Google for that or look it up on Wikipedia. Bottom of the wing slaps air down because... Well... How can it not? The wing can't move through the air without pushing air out of its way, and if the angle of attack is positive (leading edge of wing is higher than trailing edge) then "out of the way" _is_ down. Where else can the air go?

Comment: But won't the air slide somehow along the airfoil and continue into its path undiverted ?

Comment: What would make the air molecules turn around and return to the level where they previously were resting after the passing of the wing gave them downward momentum?

Comment: ,Ummm I didn't understand , could you suggest a good reference site or visual animation..... Or better still , explain in detail. Thanks